# Count totals per month per salesman

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mySQL table with orders. Each table row includes order date, amount and sales person

```
 order_id   | 
 amount     |  
 saleman_id | 
 order_date
```

I would like to query it so I can generate a HTML table with a report looking lke this.

```
 Year | Month | Total | Total for salesman 1 | Total for salesman 2 | etc...
 2014 | 10    | 5000  | 2000                 | 3000                 | etc...
 2014 | 11    | 6000  | 5000                 | 1000                 | etc...
```

This is already partially working, meaning that I have a query that allows me to create a report showing the total for every month from all salesmen but I'd like to know if there is a way to achive what I want in a single SQL query and if it's worth it performance whise. Otherwise I can just query the result for each salesman in the PHP while loop that generates th table that I already have.

Mu current query is:

```
SELECT 
YEAR(ord_date) AS year, 
MONTH(ord_date) AS month,  
ROUND(SUM(...colum calculations...),2) AS sales, 
COUNT(o.ord_id) AS count_orders 
FROM 
orders_ord AS o 
GROUP BY 
year, month
ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC;
```

I am using PHP 5.4 with the classic mysql module & mySQL5.5

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Which MySQL API are you using?

Comment: MySQL server  5.5.28, Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73

@Mike "I would like to obtain a report that shows on each row the total sales per month AND the total sales per month for each sales person" What is the SQL to use for this, if it's possible.

Comment: Meaning, `mysql_` - `mysqli_` or PDO? You want to do this in PHP I imagine? Or, just a straight SQL call?

Comment: Sorry :) I want to do this in PHP, correct. The API is I use is mysql but I can use mysqli as well.

Comment: I have edited my question to me more specific. Sorry, I am new to Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want using [`with rollup`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html):

```
SELECT YEAR(ord_date) AS year, MONTH(ord_date) AS month, repid, MONTHNAME(ord_date) AS monthname, 
       ROUND(SUM(...colum calculations...),2) AS profit,
       ROUND(SUM(...colum calculations...),2) AS sales, 
       COUNT(o.ord_id) AS count 
FROM orders_ord  o 
GROUP BY year, month
ORDER BY year DESC, month desc, repid with rollup;
```

However, because of the nature of the rollup, I would suggest combining the year and month in the `group by`:

```
SELECT YEAR(ord_date) AS year, MONTH(ord_date) AS month, repid, MONTHNAME(ord_date) AS monthname, 
       ROUND(SUM(...colum calculations...),2) AS profit,
       ROUND(SUM(...colum calculations...),2) AS sales, 
       COUNT(o.ord_id) AS count 
FROM orders_ord  o 
GROUP BY YEAR(ord_date) * 100 + MONTH(ord_date) desc, repid with rollup;
```

This will put only summary rows for individual months, rather than summaries for both the year and for the month.

Comment: Aren't rollup and order by mutually exclusive? And why is the year multiplied with 100?

Comment: @LavaRo . . . The second is so you only get one rollup row (instead of one for year and one for month).  The first is because I thought that restriction was lifted on 5.7 with the deprecation of default ordering with `group by`.  That was a misunderstanding; they are still mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your show create table it hard to give you exact query. Genarelly speeking I like to do all the work in SQL not in PHP. However, if you have a grid of data and you want to show a subtotal or a grand total then use PHP to add the rows up.

Anyhow, here are some queries that will help you

This query will give you the rounded profit and rounded sales

```
SELECT 
rep_id,
YEAR(ord_date) AS year, 
MONTH(ord_date) AS month,  
MONTHNAME(ord_date) AS monthname, 
ROUND(SUM(...colum calculations...),2) AS profit,
ROUND(SUM(...colum calculations...),2) AS sales, 
COUNT(o.ord_id) AS count 
FROM 
orders_ord AS o 
GROUP BY rep_id, year, month
ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the database do all, it is good at. (And save all the additional trips to the database, when filling in the gaps from PHP.)

```
SELECT 
YEAR(ord_date) AS year, 
MONTH(ord_date) AS month,  
MONTHNAME(ord_date) AS monthname, 
saleman_id,
ROUND(SUM(...colum calculations...),2) AS profit,
ROUND(SUM(...colum calculations...),2) AS sales, 
COUNT(o.ord_id) AS count 
FROM 
orders_ord 
GROUP BY  year, month, saleman_id

UNION ALL

SELECT 
YEAR(ord_date) AS year, 
MONTH(ord_date) AS month,  
MONTHNAME(ord_date) AS monthname,
'zzz Total zzz', 
ROUND(SUM(...colum calculations...),2) AS profit,
ROUND(SUM(...colum calculations...),2) AS sales, 
COUNT(o.ord_id) AS count 
FROM 
orders_ord 
GROUP BY  year, month
ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC;
```

To be adjusted, if year totals are really not to be provided.